# How to add a row with an autogenerated ID via EF Core using F# with a backing C# entity?

Tags: c#, f#, ef-core-2.2

My database is changing relatively quickly since I'm in early development, so I'm generating the entities via `Scaffold-DbContext`, which yields this C#:

```
public partial class User 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// And in the DbContext:
modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity => {
    entity.ToTable("User");
    entity.Property(e => e.Name)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(32)
        .IsUnicode(false);
});
```

This causes my PK to be autoincremented:

[image]

Here's my failing code:

```
module DbFactory =
    let options = DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlServer("connectionstring").Options
    let create () = new MyDb(options)
module DbService =
    let command (q) : unit =
        use db = DbFactory.create ()
        q db |> ignore
        db.SaveChanges () |> ignore
let h = User (
        Id = Unchecked.defaultof<int>, // I've also tried -1, 0, 1, null, and removing this row entirely
        Name = "bork")
DbService.command (fun db -> db.Users.Add h)
```

Since I'm setting the `Id`, EF throws the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'User' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

The error does not occur with this C# code which does not set the Id:

```
var c = new DbFactory();
var user = new User() {
  Name = "bork",
};

var db = c.Create();
db.Users.Add(user);
db.SaveChanges();
```

How can I make my F# look like it's not setting the `Id`? Since this isn't a record type (CLIMutable, I think), I've tried `User (Name = "bork")` but that also fails with the same error.

I'm new to F# too, so let me know if my F# could be cleaner.

Comment: Which version of netcore are you using ? I have made a sample trying to replicate your problem and it's working without any problem. (https://github.com/jgoday/entityframeworkcore-sample) using sqlite, a csharp library and testing from f# inserting and auto generating id.

Comment: @jgoday The problem was with code I didn't include in the question, which was dumb on my part. My mistake, sorry. I had `DbService.command (fun db -> db.Users.Remove h)` before the `Add` call, and for some infernal reason that's causing the `Id` issue. I guess the context isn't being disposed of properly? (It was in a try block in a halfhearted attempt to cleanup the database before I run a test.) Thanks for your help, you got me unstuck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jgoday taught me the importance of isolating the problem. His answer got me unstuck.